# Does the Rambam include the Afterlife in this paragraph?

Tags: rambam, gehinnom, heaven

See what the Rambam says in the paragraph linked here: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.12.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

I am looking for sources or helpful thoughts on whether the Rambam is including Rabbinic statements about Hell in this statement. He clearly says that all of these Haggados boil down to Midrashic interpretation of verses in Tanach and aren't certain. Wouldn't that mean we don't really know anything whatsoever to any degree of certainty regarding Hell? Or is Hell different for some reason?

Edit: Here are the words mainly applicable to my question with emphasis on the specific words in question: וְכָל אֵלּוּ הַדְּבָרִים **וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּהֶן** לֹא יֵדַע אָדָם אֵיךְ יִהְיוּ עַד שֶׁיִּהְיוּ. שֶׁדְּבָרִים סְתוּמִין הֵן אֵצֶל הַנְּבִיאִים. גַּם הַחֲכָמִים אֵין לָהֶם קַבָּלָה בִּדְבָרִים אֵלּוּ. אֶלָּא לְפִי הֶכְרֵעַ הַפְּסוּקִים. וּלְפִיכָךְ יֵשׁ לָהֶם מַחְלֹקֶת בִּדְבָרִים אֵלּוּ. וְעַל כָּל פָּנִים אֵין סִדּוּר הֲוָיַת דְּבָרִים אֵלּוּ וְלֹא דִּקְדּוּקֵיהֶן עִקָּר בַּדָּת. **וּלְעוֹלָם לֹא יִתְעַסֵּק אָדָם בְּדִבְרֵי הַהַגָּדוֹת. וְלֹא יַאֲרִיךְ בַּמִּדְרָשׁוֹת הָאֲמוּרִים בְּעִנְיָנִים אֵלּוּ וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּהֶן**. וְלֹא יְשִׂימֵם עִקָּר.

It's worth noting that his reasoning "and therefore there is machlokes in these things" seems to be an echo of what he says elsewhere, that anything that has machlokes is clearly not from Sinai. Unless, this is different, because maybe he is even to a tradition starting with later Prophets.

Comment: I don't see anything there about heaven or hell. Can you clarify which specific statement you're referring to?

Comment: @shmosel I am editing the question to add the words mainly applicable to my question and some explanation.

Comment: On the surface he's talking about Moshiach. I don't see why it would be relevant to heaven or hell. The existence of heaven and hell are fundamental to Judaism and one of the Rambam's 13 principles of faith. As to their nature, the Rambam describes heaven as a state of elevated comprehension of and closeness to Hashem, and hell as the inverse.

Comment: @Shmosel ??? Where does the Rambam include Hell or Heaven in his 13 principles of faith please?

Comment: As for why it would apply to those? It seems like a Kal Vachomer to me, The Messianic Age seems to be spoken of much much more than an afterlife in Tanach! Also depending on what you understand it to be referring to, the Gemara may may be an extra support to the unknown nature of the Afterlife when it says "All the Prophecies were only about the days of Messiah, as for the World to Come, "No eye has seen it other than you God".

Comment: The 11th principle is about reward and punishment, which the Rambam defines (Teshuva 9:1) as referring to the afterlife. I guess I'm still unclear on what you're trying to infer from the Rambam. If it's that we don't know much about the afterlife, that's pretty self-evident. But it's still important and relevant, unlike (in the Rambam's view) the details of what will transpire in the times of Moshiach.

Comment: I'm sorry you are correct that Heaven is included in his 11th principle, but what about hell? (The Kesef Mishna's Proof can be dismissed as referring to punishment on this world).

BTW, This, is all irrelevant, because even if the Rambam did believe in Hell as a Principle, it wouldn't exclude it from being included in the paragraph I quoted! Over there he is referring to the *details* of these topics. Therefore, just like we know Mashiach is going to come yet we don't know any details, same with the details of Heaven and Hell. This was really the intention of my original question.

Comment: @shmosel So are you saying that you do see any Midrashic descriptions of Hell as included in his statements?

Comment: I don't see a compelling reason to assume he's talking about it here. He already discussed it earlier, and he interprets (Teshuva 8:5) the descriptions as a metaphor for the soul's severance from Hashem.

Comment: That halacha in the Rambam is only addressing the pshat of the Neviims's words, he doesn't address the Midrashim there. I already explained why it should be included.
Thanks for this discussion btw!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the halakhoth are presented in Yemenite manuscripts [12:4](https://mechon-mamre.org/i/e512.htm):

> **ויש מן החכמים שאומרים שקודם ביאת המלך המשיח, יבוא אלייהו.**  וכל
> אלו הדברים וכיוצא בהן--לא יידע אדם היאך יהיו, עד שיהיו:  שדברים סתומים
> הן אצל הנביאים.  גם החכמים אין להם קבלה בדברים אלו, אלא לפי הכרע
> הפסוקים; ולפיכך יש להם מחלוקת בדברים אלו.  **ועל כל פנים, אין סידור
> הוויית דברים אלו ולא דקדוקן, עיקר בדת**.
>
> **There are some Sages who say that Elijah's coming will precede the coming of the messiah.** All these and similar matters cannot be
> definitely known by man until they occur for these matters are
> undefined in the prophets' words and even the wise men have no
> established tradition regarding these matters except their own
> interpretation of the verses. Therefore, there is a controversy among
> them regarding these matters. **Regardless of the debate concerning
> these questions, neither the order of the occurrence of these events
> or their precise detail are among the fundamental principles of the
> faith.**

12:5 thematically continues:

> **ולעולם לא יתעסק אדם בדברי ההגדות, ולא יאריך בדברי מדרשות האמורים
> בעניינים אלו וכיוצא בהן; ולא ישימם עיקר--שאינן מביאין לא לידי אהבה,
> ולא לידי יראה.**  וכן לא יחשב הקיצין; אמרו חכמים, תפוח דעתן של מחשבי
> קיצין.  אלא יחכה ויאמין בכלל הדבר, כמו שביארנו.
>
> A person should not occupy himself with the Aggadoth and Midrashim
> concerning these and similar matters, nor should he consider them as
> essentials, for study of them will neither bring fear or love of God.
> Similarly, one should not try to determine the appointed time for the
> messiah's coming. Our Sages declared: "May the spirits of those who
> attempt to determine the time of the messiah's coming expire!" Rather,
> one should await and believe in the general conception of the matter
> as explained.

I have cited these two halakhoth in toto, lest there be any ambiguity and so that we may easily reference them.

---

In 12:4 you left out the preceding clause ויש מן החכמים שאומרים שקודם ביאת המלך המשיח, יבוא אלייהו from your citation. This clause is important for understanding the context - which is what your question concerns. He is discussing the order of events in the messianic process and its details. He is asserting that there is no firm tradition on certain aspects of its details and its order and preoccupying one's self with such matters contributes nothing to proper religious development.

The Rambam is not discussing "hell" (by which I assume you intend גיהנום Gehinnom). For the Rambam, discussion of שכר ועונש (reward and punishment) of the world-to-come would be off-topic here. His focus in this subsection of the sefer is the this-worldly, political institution of monarchy. The other sections similarly concern the this-worldly political institutions of the Jewish nation (i.e. the Sanhedrin, laws of judges, testimony, etc.). It is not the after-life, it is this life. While other commentators may have merged a concept of 'olam haba (the world to come) with the messianic era (such as Nahmanides), that was not the approach and understanding of the Rambam.

In 12:5 the conjunctive indicates that this halakhah in part continues on the theme of 12:4 whose opening clause sets up the context we note above. In this halakhah he states:

> ולעולם לא יתעסק אדם בדברי ההגדות, ולא יאריך בדברי מדרשות האמורים
> בעניינים אלו וכיוצא בהן; ולא ישימם עיקר--שאינן מביאין לא לידי אהבה,
> ולא לידי יראה.
>
> A person should not occupy himself with the Aggadoth and homiletics
> concerning these and similar matters, nor should he consider them as
> essentials, for study of them will neither bring fear or love of God.

Here the Rambam makes clear that he is staying on topic (בעניינים אלו וכיוצא בהן) and warns that one should not take a deep dive on midrash/aggadah as regards this topic (the details and timing of the this worldly messianic process) for it does not bring one to greater Ahabhah and Yirah (love and awe of God). This clause similarly confirms that we are not discussing שכר ועונש (reward and punishment of the world to come). Unlike discussions such as whether Elijah will come before or after a particular date, שכר ועונש are topics whose discussion does naturally produce Ahabhah and Yirah.

IMHO based on the context, as made clear in the opening clause, the theme, and its placement in the work, it is quite evident that these two halakhoth are not about hell nor a blanket statement about Hazalic interpretations and traditions.

All the best.

Comment: My Gosh. Let me catch you up Cuz. First of all, you shouldn't answer without reading the question carefully. The very first thing I did in my post was to *include the link to the entire halacha of the Rambam*! I asked the Reader to first check out the link. Then, based on the comments that I received, I added a trimmed version to make it more for someone who was having trouble understanding which part I was referring to. Now, since you're no longer behind on all that, I am scratching my head here wondering what is up?...

Comment: You falsely accuse me of leaving out words, and then *you go ahead and leave out words!* It's fascinating! Anyway, I am limited in my time here, and cannot help out every person who isn't even doing their own part. So I just advise you to go back and read the WHOLE piece. This time including the *second part*! There is definitely a possibility that this entire piece is fundamentally including Midrashic discussions about concepts like Hell and the Afterlife. In fact, like I wrote in above comments, the Rambam leaves significant room to seriously question his belief in any sort of hell at all.

Comment: A) Your question was understood and answered. No need for all the thinly veiled animus. Keep it on topic and respond to the substance (which you appear not to have read carefully). B) I am citing the halakhah in toto as presented in Yemenite manuscripts, which are widely regarded as the most accurately reflective of the Rambam's own hand. C) The part you neglected, which I foremost draw attention to is the clause that presents the context (i.e. ויש מן החכמים שאומרים שקודם ביאת המלך המשיח, יבוא אלייהו). There is no question that he is discussing the sequence and details of messianic events.

Comment: The following is copied and pasted from the link that you miraculously failed once again to simply click on. וְיֵשׁ מִן הַחֲכָמִים שֶׁאוֹמְרִים שֶׁקֹּדֶם בִּיאַת הַמָּשִׁיחַ יָבוֹא אֵלִיָּהוּ. וְכָל אֵלּוּ הַדְּבָרִים וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּהֶן לֹא יֵדַע אָדָם אֵיךְ יִהְיוּ עַד שֶׁיִּהְיוּ.
There is no difference between that, and the "Yemenite Tradition" that you uselessly provided. So, now that that dishonesty with that smokescreen has been exposed, you can retreat and move on to trolling someone else's sincere post.

Comment: Again with the personal and unnecessary attacks (dishonesty, smokescreens, trolling, etc.). Where this animus arises from is a mystery. I highly advise that you take a look inside and try to figure out where the tone is coming from. All the best in that endeavor.

Comment: All that aside: I have checked in the Qafih edition as well, which confirms that it is not just the manuscripts that Mechon-Mamre utilizes but R. Qafih's as well that has it this way. It is the structure and break up of the halakhah as originally formulated that you are ignoring here. To me it seems abundantly evident and clear that when the Rambam states that there is no qabala (i.e. received tradition) the context of the statement is specifically in regards to the order and details of the messianic process.

Comment: The next halakhah, begins ולעולם לא יתעסק אדם בדברי ההגדות and concerns another issue (i.e. the prohibition against trying to predict/time the messianic era).

Comment: If your point is that in some versions it's split up in middle, why don't you just say that? You literally haven't mentioned that point at all until just now where you still only hint to it! Either way, now that there's finally something substantial to respond to, I appreciate the insight. I still don't think it makes a difference, as he anyways continues on to say וְלֹא יַאֲרִיךְ בַּמִּדְרָשׁוֹת הָאֲמוּרִים בְּעִנְיָנִים אֵלּוּ וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּהֶן which implies the connection in flow of both paragraphs, and the bunching of *this topic* together with *similar ones*, is my questions main source.

Comment: As it seems to have gotten by you, I'll edit and elaborate for your edification. Next time please refrain from all of the vitriol which was altogether unnecessary.

Comment: I like that which you said about Schar and Onesh indeed leading to Ahavah and Yirah. However, based on my understanding of the Rambam's views expressed in his introduction to Chelek, he doesn't see fear or love caused by reward or punishment as a value. However, to this you may object and say that the effect of understanding these realities is itself a manifestation of Chochma which the Rambam does admire. This is a bit of a questionable idea of which I'd have to think about... Otherwise, you can just say the Rambam is speaking on a practical level for those who need motivation Shelo Lishma.